# Android createDebugCoverageReport doesn't show coverage anymore

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

Running `./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport` with Android gradle plugin v1.3.1 used to give me an html file that included code coverage percentage.

Now with gradle 1.5.0 and even with 2.0.0-alpha7 the report is much more limited, and doesn't show coverage percentage.

How can I reenable the coverage report?

Here's my gradle config:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha7'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "some.id"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23

        testApplicationId applicationId + ".test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // ...
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed a similar behavior after running my tests with coverage.  When I opened up index.html it just showed me which tests passed and which ones failed.  It was not giving me the coverage percentages that I was used to seeing.

Here is an image of what I was seeing. As you can see, there are no percentage numbers to be found.
[image]

Then I realized that I was looking in the wrong folder!  The above screenshot comes from:
**build/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html**

The place you can go to see your coverage percentage is: 
**build/reports/coverage/debug/index.html**
[image]

Based on the information you provided, I am not sure if you were making the same mistake I made by looking in the wrong place.  I figured I would post my answer as it may help someone that was lost in the same way I was lost.

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely helpful. I also realized that no coverage report is generated if any of your tests fail.

Comment: That's why I can't find the report